# Printing "*" characters separated by dashes with the print function's "sep" parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and just trying to figure out how I can print multiple `"*"` characters separated by dashes but in such a way that the number of asterisks and dashes can be changed by the user.

This is what I have so far:

```
print('*' * n, sep = '-' * m)
```

Where n and m are integers. but its not really working.

The result I want (if n = 3 and m = 2) is:

```
*--*--*
```

Comment: What output do you want for n=5 m=2?

Comment: ahh sorry I messed up, I mean to say 3,2 would return *--*--*

Comment: I think you want n number of *'s and in bettween *'s m number of -'s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> print(*['*']*n, sep='-'*m)
*--*--*
```

For just single characters this will work too:

```
>>> print(*('*'*n), sep='-'*m) #this can fail if you use `'**'` instead of `'*'`
*--*--*
```

`['*']*n` creates a list here, now we unpack this list to `print()` using `*` and use `'-'*m` as `sep`.:

```
>>> ['*']*n
['*', '*', '*']
```

Comment: `sep=` ?? in Python3.x ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It is py3.x specific, you can also import `print()` function in py2.x: `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sep = '-'
>>> n = 11
>>> print sep.join('*'*n)
*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sep=("".join(["-"] * m))
print(sep.join(["*"] * n))
```

`n` number of `*` and in bettween `*` `m` number of `-`

`n=5`, `m=4` gives the following pattern.

```
*----*----*----*----*
```

`n=3`, `m=2` gives the following pattern.

```
*--*--*
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not bad too:

```
print ('-'*m).join(['*']*n)
```

Comment: You could do `('-'*m).join(['*']*n)` to get the extra dashes where they're wanted.

Comment: In python 3.2.3
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'    But in python 2.7.3 It work perfectly. ('-'*m).join does not work in python 3.2.3

Comment: You can remove the `[]` also.  `join` takes a sequence and `'*'*n` is a sequence of characters.

Comment: @jimifiki You need to add an extra pair of parenthesis: `print (('-'*m).join(['*']*n))`